# what type of data is needed to learn machine learning create logo

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images

Can anybody suggest, what type of data is needed to  learn machine learning create logo.What variables should I take to train a neural network? The bigger, the better.Can someone have experience and be able to prompt on what data to train. I.E. What data i should collect?

Comment: there is a host of "this __ does not exist" going around (e.g. https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/). See if you can find one with open source code and then copy it for logos.

Comment: @philshem, thanks but were in this link data for train?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entire framework is outlined here

**[LLD - Large Logo Dataset](https://data.vision.ee.ethz.ch/sagea/lld/)** - including training dataset downloads

> Training Generative Adversarial Networks (GANs) for logo synthesis on such multi-modal data is not straightforward and results in mode collapse for some state-of-the-art methods. We propose the use of synthetic labels obtained through clustering to disentangle and stabilize GAN training. We are able to generate a high diversity of plausible logos and we demonstrate latent space exploration techniques to ease the logo design task in an interactive manner.

[Code repository](https://github.com/alex-sage/logo-gen/)

---

License:

> Please notice that this dataset is made available for academic research purposes only. All the images are collected from the Internet, and the copyright belongs to the original owners.

[image]

Comment: Just i can say. Perfect!!!

Comment: how do you think, what CPU,RAM, and Video card needed to learn the neural networks of such type?

Comment: Depends how much time you have to wait. Try the AI site